# how to give relative path in drupal for setting an image

Tags: 7, media

**Hi all,
      iam trying to set image here in a module .The image is in the same module folder. but iam not able to get the image path**

```
<td><img src="projectsetup.jpg "  width="42" height="42"></td>
```

**This is the error which iam getting ..cleary states no path**

[image]

> How to get a relative path in module to display images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal has ways to get the relative path from document root but not for individual module/theme folder.

You can get the path to current module or theme using `path_to_theme`

```
<img src="/<?php echo path_to_theme() ?>/images/projectsetup.jpg"/>
```

[path_to_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7.x) from the documentation

> Returns the path to the current themed element.
>
> It can point to the active theme or the module handling a themed implementation. For example, when invoked within the scope of a theming call it will depend on where the theming function is handled. If implemented from a module, it will point to the module. If implemented from the active theme, it will point to the active theme. When called outside the scope of a theming call, it will always point to the active theme.

Comment: @GiorgoskK: Madhu is talking about the module, not the theme. path_to_theme will give the path to theme folder, not the module.

Comment: @jeetendra My answer is still correct was just not answered properly so i revised ... so I don't understand the reason for downvoting

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'myModule') . 'image/projectsetup.jpg';
```

now set src = '$path' into your .module file where you set image src.